# Ionic does not building android project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am trying to build or run my ionic 4 project for android platform, but it is not working. I am getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide which version of google play services/ firebase version you are using?
or you can check the  issue here https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1066

Answer (score 0):

I assuming error from `cordova-plugin-firebase` related plugin. Remove that firebase plugin and execute `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex` instead. Install plugin `cordova-plugin-firebasex` using cordova will automatic install firebase required adapter plugins for android. Update cordova to 9.0.0 and android to 8.1.0. These steps above solved my problem last time.